Ansible playbook to execute the tasks sequentially based on external deployment file
I have logic descriptor file whose content is like this
UI|create_dir|/opt/aaaHome/sdlc_test/configuration/bbb_UI/47.0.0
UI|create_dir|/opt/aaaHome/sdlc_test/configuration/bbb_UI/47.0.0/ttt
UI|create_dir|/opt/aaaHome/sdlc_test/configuration/bbb_UI/47.0.0/Application
UI|create_dir|/opt/aaaHome/sdlc_test/configuration/bbb_UI/47.0.0/ServicesManager
UI|Copy|configuration_47.0.0.xml|/opt/aaaHome/sdlc_test/configuration/bbb_UI/47.0.0/Application/
Batch|Copy,Execute|sqlFile.sql|/tmp/aml_work/
UI|Copy|services_47.0.0.xml|/opt/aaaHome/sdlc_test/configuration/bbb_UI/47.0.0/ServicesManager/
UI|Copy|filtering.zip|/opt/aaaHome/sdlc_test/configuration/bbb_UI/47.0.0/ttt
UI|Copy|47.0.0.lst|/opt/aaaHome/sdlc_test/conf/importexport/
UI|Create_file|47.0.0.lst.flag|/opt/aaaHome/sdlc_test/conf/importexport/
UI|Modify|base_config.properties|/opt/aaaHome/sdlc_test/conf|system.authentication=INTERNAL

I need to take actions as mentioned in this file sequentially line by line using ansible. Here's how to read the file.

1st separator is name of the remote server (UI/batch) where the task is going to execute.
2nd separator is the action to take createDir/copyTheFile/copy&Execute/ModifyTheFile
3rd separator is where to copy OR which name of dir to be created
4th separator is in case of modify action what's the content to modify

Here's the ansible playbook flow how I have thought of
(1) main-playbook.yml
- name: Deployment
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Read lines from pilot file
      shell: cat logicDescriptor.txt
      register: logic_file_content
    - name: Execute actions based on logic.txt content
      include_tasks: "logic-deployment.yml"
      vars:
        logic_content: "{{ logic_file_content.stdout_lines }}"

(2) logic-deployment.yml
- name: Execute actions based on logicDescriptor.txt content
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Include specific tasks based on logicDescriptor.txt content
      include_tasks: tasks/{{ item.split('|')[1] }}.yml
      loop: "{{ logic_content }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item

(3) tasks/create_dir.yml, tasks/copy.yml, tasks/create_file.yml etc.
tasks/create_dir.yml
- name: Create directory
  hosts: UI
  tasks:
    - name: Create directory
      file:
        path: "{{ item.split('|')[2] }}"
        state: directory
      with_items: "{{ logic_file_content.stdout_lines }}"
      when: "item.split('|')[1] == 'create_dir' and item.split('|')[0] == 'UI'"

tasks/create_file.yml
- name: Create file
  hosts: UI
  tasks:
    - name: Create file
      file:
        path: "{{ item.split('|')[3] }}/{{ item.split('|')[2] }}"
        state: touch
      with_items: "{{ logic_file_content.stdout_lines }}"
      when: "item.split('|')[1] == 'Create_file' and item.split('|')[0] == 'UI'"

However this is not working. I am getting error on 2nd ansible playbook logic-deployment.yml

ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, tasks`

I have removed name, hosts, tasks directives and tried to run then I got the same error  on 3rd ansible playbook tasks/create_dir.yml however here we need hosts part because we need to execute the tasks on this particular host. And its possible that on the same create_dir.yml could have 2 tasks for 2 diff. hosts so cannot put one host at the parent level.
How to resolve this issue?

You're confusing tasks with playbooks so it makes sense to start from the basics.
If you want to have separate playbooks, you have to use import_playbook instead but it can't be used on a task level (so it can't be used in a loop). And then you'll run into the fact that your logic_file_content is quite hard to share between the plays.
I honestly don't think that it makes sense to use these "logic descriptors" as an input because their format brings so much unnecessary complexity into your playbooks even for simplest actions that it seems to be quicker to write everything from scratch.
If you still have strong reasons to continue you can proceed with the current approach except that you'll have to:

include tasks, not playbooks;
add the check of target host (via ansible_host or inventory_hostname) into the when condition for each task.

Also, I'd recommend to have a look at Whats the difference between ansible 'raw', 'shell' and 'command'? and Difference between "command" or specific module execution in Ansible.
